# Node.js body-parser won't parse input names with square brackets in json

Tags: json, node.js, parsing, express, body-parser

I have a problem with Express body-parser in Node.js

I have inputs like this:

```
<input id="personEmail1" type="email" name="person[0][email]" placeholder="Email1" class="form-control">
<input id="personEmail2" type="email" name="person[1][email]" placeholder="Email2" class="form-control">
```

After when I submit my form I got this in my console.log:

```
{ 'person[0][email]': 'info@sss.sss', 'person[1][email]': 'info@ggg.ggg' }
```

But I want it to be parsed in json format:

```
{ person: [{email: 'info@sss.sss'}, {email: 'info@ggg.ggg'}] }
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I have the same issue. The answer in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/how-do-you-extract-post-data-in-node-js, Instead of getting `request.body.user.name`, I got {"user[name]", '...'}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

for express version 4.x when you need to manually install body-parser and multer, and you want to get nested properties from the post, e.g. `data[test]` in the form of `req.body.data.test`, you need to set:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the Express body-parser middleware bracket notation correctly.  But, as an example of what can be done...

Using this view:

```
<form method="post">
    <label for="person_email_1">Email address 1</label>
    <input id="person_email_1" name="person[0][email]" type="email" value="email1@example.com"> <br>

    <label for="person_email_2">Email address 2</label>
    <input id="person_email_2" name="person[1][email]" type="email" value="email2@example.com"> <br>

    <button type="submit">Submit v1</button>
</form>
<br>
<form method="post">
    <label for="person_email_1">Email address 1</label>
    <input id="person_email_1" name="person[email][0]" type="email" value="email1@example.com"> <br>

    <label for="person_email_2">Email address 2</label>
    <input id="person_email_2" name="person[email][1]" type="email" value="email2@example.com"> <br>

    <button type="submit">Submit v2a</button>
</form>
<br>
<form method="post">
    <label for="person_email_1">Email address 1</label>
    <input id="person_email_1" name="person[email]" type="email" value="email1@example.com"> <br>

    <label for="person_email_2">Email address 2</label>
    <input id="person_email_2" name="person[email]" type="email" value="email2@example.com"> <br>

    <button type="submit">Submit v2b</button>
</form>
<br>
<form method="post">
    <label for="person_email_1_address">Email address 1</label>
    <input id="person_email_1_address" name="person[emailAddresses][0][address]" type="email" value="email1@example.com">
    <input id="person_email_1_description" name="person[emailAddresses][0][description]" type="text" value="lorem ipsum 1"> <br>

    <label for="person_email_2_address">Email address 2</label>
    <input id="person_email_2_address" name="person[emailAddresses][1][address]" type="email" value="email2@example.com">
    <input id="person_email_2_description" name="person[emailAddresses][1][description]" type="text" value="lorem ipsum 2"> <br>

    <button type="submit">Submit v3</button>
</form>
```

...and this post handler:

```
function postHandler(req, res) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body)); // show in console
    res.send(req.body); // show in browser
}
```

Version 1 (your version, which works for me, and returns your desired result) req.body:

```
{
  "person": [
    {"email": "email1@example.com"},
    {"email": "email2@example.com"}
  ]
}
```

Versions 2a & 2b (an array of strings, with/without index number) req.body:

```
{
  "person": {
    "email": [
      "email1@example.com",
      "email2@example.com"
    ]
  }
}
```

Version 3 (an array of objects) req.body:

```
{
  "person": {
    "emailAddresses": [
      {
        "address": "email1@example.com",
        "description": "lorem ipsum 1"
      },
      {
        "address": "email2@example.com",
        "description": "lorem ipsum 2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I've personally used versions 2 & 3 on a node/Express/jquery/Bootstrap line of business app where a person or business account can have unlimited telephone numbers, email addresses, and URLs.  The body-parser bracket notation made it stupid easy.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you've used valid Javascript syntax for your keys, they are still just strings and **no** JSON parser will attempt to call [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) on them.

However, JSON already has a concept of arrays, which should work in the way you are expecting them to.

It would be useful to show us the code in which the call to `console.log` happens. But I would guess that instead, you need to rethink the naming convention for your field names.

```
<input id="personEmail1" type="email" name="personEmail1" placeholder="Email1" class="form-control">
<input id="personEmail2" type="email" name="personEmail2" placeholder="Email2" class="form-control">
```

Then create the Javascript object from that data.

```
function handler(req, res) {
   var people = [
     { email: req.body.personEmail1 },
     { email: req.body.personEmail2 }
   ];

   console.log(people[0]); // person 1
   console.log(people[1]); // person 2
   console.log(people);    // both people
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this https://github.com/macek/jquery-serialize-object to serialize my form as JSON. It parses data as I want and it's easy to use.

```
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      data: $form.serializeJSON(),
      contentType: 'application/json',
      url: $url,
      success: function (result) { ... }
    });
```

I think this is the easyest